# Type unknown during compile time in Julia

Tags: types, julia, matrix-multiplication, dispatch

I want to write a Julia program which performs matrix operations such as matrix multiplication, diagonalization, etc. The matrices are user given and read from a file.
All matrix operations are formally identical for real or complex matrices, so this is actually a perfect example for a multiple dispatch design Julia. I only have to write one single code, which can handle both cases, all real or all complex.

For instance, I could write all function arguments like

```
function MatrixOperations(M1::Matrix{<:Number})::Matrix{<:Number}
# my code
end
```

However, if the matrices are all real or all complex is decided only during runtime (via user input).

What is best practice to treat this scenario?

In principle the following would do the job:

```
# user given type info in string TypeInfo
if TypeInfo == "real"
    M = Matrix{Float64}(undef, size)
else
    M = Matrix{ComplexF64}(undef, size)
end
read!("matrixfile.bin", M)
```

However, my gut feeling tells me that

1. this is awkward / unprofessional code design
2. this can affect the performance of the matrix operations, since the compiler might not be able to optimize the code.

Are there more elegant ways to handle that in Julia? What would be best practice here?

Comment: fyi, there is no type such as `Complex64`, you should be using `ComplexF64` which is basically the same as `Complex{Float64}`

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it in my question.

Comment: What is the file format used in `matrixfile.bin`? The only design that makes sense is to have all type information about an object serialized on disc should be contained in the file itself and nothing should be specified externally by the user. Consider using something like JLD2.jl (https://github.com/JuliaIO/JLD2.jl) to store and load your matrices.

Comment: With "user given" I simply mean that the user provides the matrix data and my program cannot know if it contains real or complex data during compile time. This information can, of course, be included in matrixfile.bin. Or think of HDF5 instead. My main point is, that the information of the type is only available during runtime. My program reads all the information and only then the type is known.

Comment: In fact, this problem is perfect for multiple-dispatch in Julia. You, literally, have to do nothing. Leave the type of the matrices unspecified in your code, and Julia will compile the right version of the functions according to the type of the input matrix, and it will optimize for the specific type. This is one of those cases where you can lie back and let Julia do its thing.

Comment: And how would the then look like? How to declare M? The problem is that ```read!("matrixfile.bin", M)``` will crash if matrixfile.bin contains complex matrix elements and M was not declared as ComplexF64.

Comment: I would use the code you suggested in your OP. I do not see how it is awkward. Naturally, the `read!` call will be dynamically dispatched, but that is just a fundamental constraint in your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements, as I understand them:

- You get a user-provided file containing data for a matrix
- You can only tell the element type by inspecting a user-provided string
- You must provide a pre-allocated matrix to be filled in from the file.

Given these points, I don't see any way outside of using a branch (if/else, ternary operator, or try/catch), and then creating a matrix based on that.

The best solution is the one you suggested in your OP:

```
# user given type info in string TypeInfo
if TypeInfo == "real"
    M = Matrix{Float64}(undef, size)
else
    M = Matrix{ComplexF64}(undef, size)
end
read!("matrixfile.bin", M)
```

It is simple and clear, and will also be efficient. There is a cost to dynamic dispatch, but it will probably be in the microseconds range, so as long as it happens a single time, it is negligible. The problem with dynamic dispatch is mainly when it occurs millions of times inside a hot loop.

Comment: why does the user provided thing have to be a string? why can't it be a type?

Comment: I don't know, but I presume it's not being entered within Julia itself but through a CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator here if you want to make it a bit elegant.

```
# user given type info in string TypeInfo
T = TypeInfo == "real" ? Float64 : ComplexF64
read!("matrixfile.bin", Matrix{T}(undef, size))
```

It should work as intended.

Comment: It's indeed a more elegant formulation of my approach. But is it best practice? If my function returns this matrix, then the return type of my function is unclear during runtime.

Comment: using strings for this is bad. Julia has a type system for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the `similar` function. This lets you make a matrix of the same size as and type as another matrix (or lets you change the type or size).

If that isn't what you're looking for, you can instead use parametric types.

```
function MatrixOperations(M1::Matrix{T})::Matrix{T} where {T<:Number}
    if T <:Real
        ...
    else
        ...
    end
end
```

This has a few advantages over the string approach. It means the user doesn't have to give another argument, and the compiler will be able to get rid of the branch at compile time since the computation is purely in the type domain.

If your `Complex` case and `Real` case algorithms are pretty different, I would instead recommend using multiple dispatch.

```
function MatrixOperations(M1::Matrix{<:Real})::Matrix{<:Complex}
    ...
end
function MatrixOperations(M1::Matrix{<:Real})::Matrix{<:Real}
    ...
end
```

Comment: But, you can't dispatch on output types. Also, there's nothing to dispatch on, only an input file containing data and a user-supplied string. There's simply no type information whatsoever, I cannot see any alternative to a branch and dynamic dispatch.

Comment: the question had a matrix coming in so you can dispatch on that.

Comment: I didn't get that, only a file from which to read a matrix, and a string to tell you the type.